# Selenium WebDriver with ASP.NET controls

Tags: css, selenium, css-selectors

I'm trying to find elements on a web page that is created using ASP.NET. The problem is ASP.NET prior to version 4.0 generates some long names for the controls so to find a simple "Username" input field I need to use its full name:

```
var elementName = "LoginControl1_uxLoginControl_UserName";
var username = Browser.TryFind(By.Name(elementName));
```

and it seems to be working, but I'm looking for something simpler. Is it possible to do the same thing using partial element names or partial Ids? e.g.

```
var username = Browser.TryFind(By.CssSelector("UserName"));
```

this should return all the elements that have "UserName" in their names/ids (or even the first element).

Comment: If you need a reference, visit the [Selectors spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using xpath,

```
var username = Browser.TryFind(By.Xpath("//*[contains( @name , 'UserName')] "));
```

The other option is to used a css selector if possible

Comment: Using XPath definitely is a good choice. @Oliver, what did you mean by "your now limited to only on type of tag" ?

Comment: if you look at the XPath you are now selecting all input tag with a name that contains UserName. Before this would work they any HTML element with a name UserName. Sorry wasn't clear

Comment: @Oliver: You can easily replace `input` with `*`, no?

Answer (score 2):

Try using one of the [substring matching attribute selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#attribute-substrings):

```
var username = Browser.TryFind(By.CssSelector("[id$='UserName']"));
```

That matches any element with an ID ending with `UserName`.